# SQLAlchemy query by .contains string

Tags: sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi I’m really new to SQLAlchemy, sqlite and Flask and am Querying from a database with the following code

```
db.session_qry(Kinase).filter(Kinase.Gene_Synonyms.contains(srch_strg)
```

However when the `srch_strg = ‘PKB’` 
The query returns multiple rows from the `Gene_Synonyms` column as in this column there are 2 rows, one has (PKB RAC) and the other has just (PKBG) thus why I had to use .contains and not iLike as some rows contains multiple gene name synonyms. 
Therefore I get both PKB and PKBG 
.
 I tried

```
db.session_qry(Kinase).filter(Kinase.Gene_Synonyms.contains(‘%’+str(srch_strg)+’%’)
```

as recommended in a similar question posted on stackoverflow as well as

```
db.session_qry(Kinase).filter(Kinase.Gene_Synonyms.filter_by(’%’+str(srch_strg)+’%’)
```

but again keep getting both PKB and PKBG whereas I just want the exact srch_strg which is PKB

Comment: You may want to format your data in an other way in this Gene_Synonyms column. To me it seems quite tricky to filter just with a string. Eventually you could search with `srch_str = "PKB "` but I dont think it is exactly what you want. In the end, wether you use `contains` or `ilike`, the columns with matching strings will be returned by the query.

Comment: thanks, I managed to do it after changing the format of the strings inside the column so that they were in a csv format and that way the ',' enabled exact string matches